# Get a value with the highest level from a different data

Tags: r

Suppose I have data including some information of names and scores in school.

```
name = c('Ann','Dann','Pann', 'Sam', 'Lora', 'Peter')
score = c(30,30,50,70,20,10)
school = data.frame(name=name, score=score)
```

I may use 'which.max' to find the highest level of the data.

```
data = school[which.max(school$score),]
data$name
[1] Sam
```

Now I want to find the name with the highest score in Aclass set.

```
Aclass = c('Peter','Pann', 'Lora', 'Smith')
```

The outcome should be

```
[1] 'Pann'
```

Please notice 'Smith' is not a part of school data.
Regardless of how many new names are included in Aclass, what I want to find is just a name with the highest score in school data. What code should I make to get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method searches through a subset of the data.frame school using `with` to reduce typing.

```
with(school[school$name %in% Aclass,], name[which.max(score)])

[1] Pann
Levels: Ann Dann Lora Pann Peter Sam
```

Comment: Also `school$name[which.max(school$score*(school$name %in% Aclass))]` which avoids a subsetting.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you.